# Show two tables data in one method in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have populate User.all query to getting the all users information using the following code.

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  if @users.exists?
    render json: @users
  else
    render json: { 'status' => 'S1000', 'description' => 'No users are registered' }
  end
end
```

It resturns the all user details like as follow

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "first_name": "Gunapala",
    "last_name": "Ratmalana",
    "email": "guna@gmai.com",
    "contact_number": "97866565",
    "user_name": "gunapala",
    "password": "12345",
    "created_at": "2017-01-05T08:10:36.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-05T08:10:36.000Z",
    "is_active": true
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "first_name": "Nifras",
    "last_name": "nifras",
    "email": "dfjndjf@dffjnd.dfjn",
    "contact_number": "djfndj",
    "user_name": "464555",
    "password": "fddfdf",
    "created_at": "2017-01-05T08:33:39.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-05T08:33:39.000Z",
    "is_active": true
  }
]
```

I have another has_many relationship table called roles_users. ( This table contains the information of user roles. )

```
table : roles_users
+---------+---------+
| role_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |      13 |
|       1 |      14 |
|       2 |      13 |
|       2 |      14 |
|       3 |      14 |
+---------+---------+

table : roles
+----+-----------+
| id | role_name |   
+----+-----------+
|  1 | admin     | 
|  2 | user      |
|  3 | temp_user |
+----+-----------+
```

Now I need to add this information too to my previous User.all records. How do I populate on the same method.

My expected result would be

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "first_name": "Gunapala",
    "last_name": "Ratmalana",
    "email": "guna@gmai.com",
    "contact_number": "97866565",
    "user_name": "gunapala",
    "password": "12345",
    "created_at": "2017-01-05T08:10:36.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-05T08:10:36.000Z",
    "is_active": true,
    "roles": [ "admin", "user" ]
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "first_name": "Nifras",
    "last_name": "nifras",
    "email": "dfjndjf@dffjnd.dfjn",
    "contact_number": "djfndj",
    "user_name": "464555",
    "password": "fddfdf",
    "created_at": "2017-01-05T08:33:39.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-05T08:33:39.000Z",
    "is_active": true,
    "roles": [ "admin", "user","temp_user" ]
  }
]
```

Comment: So the association is like: user has many roles, and roles has many users?

Comment: user has many roles is the association

Comment: Sorry the both way. A role has many users and a user has many roles

Answer (score 3):

Include the association with `to_json`

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  if @users.exists?
    render :json => @users.to_json(include: :roles)
  else
    render :json => { "status" => 'S1000', "description" => 'No users are registered' }
  end
end
```

Refer [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) for more details

Comment: I didn't get the roles. I got the same results which i have previously

Comment: I have try on the console too

Comment: a minor change I made in your code. It's work . The change is `@users.to_json(:include => :roles)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). It allows you to define any JSON structure by creating a file `app/views/users/index.json.jbuilder`
It's pretty much a standard solution for JSON API in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

add this to Gemfile

`gem 'active_model_serializers'`

after `bundle install`

add this file to `app/serializers/user_serializer.rb` (you can user generator)

```rb
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,:first_name,:last_name, :email,:contact_number, :user_name, :password, :created_at, :updated_at, :is_active

  has_many: roles
end
```